# How to get the public key in form of JWS Key set

Tags: apex, controller, single-sign-on, authentication, custom-controller

I have a JWT Class which generates JWT Token using Private key. Now, I need to expose an endpoint for exernal application to get the public key in the form of JWKS KeySet.
Can anyone guide me how to achieve this scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JWKS is [located](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57085381/how-does-jwt-io-already-know-my-public-key/) based on a URL specified in OpenID Connect metadata. The discovery of OIDC metadata uses a special endpoint that Salesforce already [provides](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_using_openid_discovery_endpoint.htm&type=5) out of the box and you won't be able to override it. Ship your public key to the other party via an out-of-band means or use Salesforce's out of the box support for [issuing JWTs](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/269385/named-credentials-what-is-the-difference-between-jwt-jwt-token-exchange).

Answer (score 1):

The Salesforce OpenID configuration exposes the JWKS information. Take this one as an example: `https://de03-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/.well-known/openid-configuration`. Look for `jwks_uri` and follow that URL to `https://de03-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/id/keys`. This will contain the key material you need.

Comment: The keys are only in RSA algorithm format