# Call Pardot APIs from Apex: obtaining the access token

Tags: apex, callout, pardot

I am trying to get a token in apex code so that I can save this in a custom object -- This token once retrieved will be further used to access Pardot from Salesforce via apex code.

While running the below class code, I am getting the following error.

I am also attaching Named Credentials and Auth. Provider in screenshot.

I am in a developer sandbox, and trying to get token through the URL specified in the named credential.

**ERROR:**

caused by: System.UnexpectedException: You don't have permission to view this data. Ask your administrator to set up authentication for the external data source.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**CLASS CODE**

```apex
public class Sf2PardotAuth implements Queueable,Database.AllowsCallouts{
    
    public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
        
        
        //Metadata to hold key info.
        PardotAuthFocus__c  creds = [SELECT ConsumerKey__c, ConsumerSecret__c, GrantType__c, Password__c,
                                     Username__c FROM PardotAuthFocus__c];
        
        SYSTEM.debug('CREDENTIAL LIST::::' + creds);
        
        String request_body = 'grant_type=' + creds.GrantType__c + '&client_id=' + creds.ConsumerKey__c 
                            + '&client_secret=' + creds.ConsumerSecret__c + '&username=' + creds.Username__c
                            +   '&password=' + creds.Password__c;
        
        System.debug('REQUEST BODY:::::' +request_body );
        
        //Declare the Instantiation request variable to send as Http request
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        
        //Formation of HTTP initial request
        request.setBody(request_body);
        request.setMethod('POST');
        request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        request.setEndpoint('callout:SF2Pardot');
        
        //Send http request 
        Http http_var = new Http();
            
        Httpresponse response_rec = http_var.send(request);
        
        //Check for Successful response
        if(response_rec.getStatusCode() == 200){
            System.debug(response_rec.getBody());
        }
           
        
    }
}
```

Comment: You're mixing two different approaches for getting the token: the out of the box no-code approach with Auth Provider versus the Apex-based solution. Choose one. See [this Q&A](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/332120/how-to-create-named-principal-named-credentials-for-salesforce-itself-as-an-id) for an almost complete example.

Comment: @identigral would you able to help me with apex code? And why are we getting stuck? I need to store that token in a custom field so that it can be added to other APIs that will require this token.

Comment: Named Credentials with auth provider will store the token for you. This type of question (getting a token from a 3rd party) is frequently asked and answered on here  + you have an almost-working example linked in our comment above.

Comment: @identigral i resolved the issue by not using Named Credential, using the endpoint directly, and it returned a token which I am now able to save without any extra steps. The endpoint did not need to have a callout: Named Credential as I would eventually have to supply username, password and client keys in the HTTP request body anyway.

Comment: No, you don't _have_ to supply username or password. That is only true for Client Creds flow which is insecure for a reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by not
using Named Credential, using the
endpoint directly, and it returned a
token which I am now able to save
without any extra steps. The endpoint
did not need to have a callout: Named
Credential as I would eventually have to
supply username, password and client
keys in the HTTP request body anyway.

Comment: The point of named credentials is to remove username, pwd, keys from APEX code and (potentially) insecure configuration.   Though yes, choosing to do it entirely manually is certainly a way to make it function, it is not necessary and against best practices.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your screenshots, the Named Credential URL should be `https://pi.demo.pardot.com` for the URL (using `https://pi.pardot.com` for Production).

Your class code can effectively be thrown away. We have a github project that demonstrates how you can call the Pardot API here: https://github.com/sercante-llc/pardot-publisher-sfdx

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
req.setHeader('Pardot-Business-Unit-Id', '0Uvxxxxxxxxxxx');

req.setEndpoint('callout:'+NAMED_CREDENTIAL+'/v5/objects/prospects/do/upsertLatestByEmail');
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setBody(jsonString);
```

If it helps, I've written a blog post that goes through all details for setting up the scenario that you are describing here: https://thespotforpardot.com/2021/02/02/pardot-api-and-getting-ready-with-salesforce-sso-users-part-3a-connecting-to-pardot-api-from-apex/ (note that this blog post walks you through the JWT Token OAuth flow, though as I've learned more since the Client Credentials flow MIGHT be a better approach)

Comment: The github link is a 404. While the blog may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. JWT Bearer is still a preferred flow for this type of interface.

Comment: sorry, fixed the 404 (didn't realize it was a private repo)