# Can we store a signing key in a Named Credential and use it via apex to generate a new JWT token

Tags: apex, namedcredentials, jwt

I have a requirement where I need to generate a new JWT token for authentication but we cannot hard code the signing key in apex or store the signing key in a Custom Metadata or Settings. So wanted to check if Named Credentials be used to store security/signing keys and then can be accessed via apex when generating a new JWT token?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate JWT token for external app](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/324426/generate-jwt-token-for-external-app)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Named Credentials are a feature in Salesforce that allows you to store the URL and authentication parameters of an external service in one definition, and then use it as the endpoint for [callouts](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_named_credentials.htm). Named Credentials can support different authentication protocols, such as **OAuth 2.0**, **JWT Bearer Token**, or **Basic Authentication**.

However, [Named Credentials](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.named_credentials_about.htm&type=5) cannot be used to store security or signing keys for generating a new JWT token in Apex. This is because Named Credentials do not expose the stored credentials to Apex, and only use them internally when making a callout. Therefore, you cannot access the signing key from a Named Credential and use it to create a JWT token in Apex.

Instead, you can use the following methods to store and access the signing key for generating a JWT token in Apex:

- Use a custom object or a custom setting to store the signing key as an **[encrypted](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.security_pe_enable_custom_fields.htm&type=5)** field. You can then query the field value in Apex and decrypt it using the **[Crypto](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_classes_restful_crypto.htm)** class. This method is more secure than hard-coding the signing key in Apex, but it still requires you to manage the encryption and decryption of the key.