# Importing a Java keystore (JKS) yields a "Keystore file is corrupted" message

Tags: certificates

You have a Java keystore (JKS) file with a public/private keypair that you're importing via Certificate and Key Management. When you do so, you see an error message: `Error: keystore file is corrupted`:

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The root cause of this issue is the change of default keystore format in Java 9:

> For approximately two decades, Java and `keytool` had relied on the
> JDK-specific `JKS` keystore type as its default store. As specified by
> JEP 229, JDK9 transitions the default keystore to `PKCS12`

As of this writing (Spring '23), SF wants the legacy JKS format. If you're building the JKS by yourself via `keytool`, do this:

- [Java 9 or newer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57363446/how-to-know-the-jdk-version-on-my-machine): add `-deststoretype JKS` to `keytool -importkeystore...` command
- [Java is older than 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57363446/how-to-know-the-jdk-version-on-my-machine): no change. Run `keytool -importkeystore...` as usual without the extra `-deststoretype..` arg.

Comment: Error: The key used for "localhost" is not an RSA key. Sigh Salesforce doesn't allow ECDSA

Comment: https://prnt.sc/pfMTA1q8y3OP screenshot for above